# How do I resize the header of a uitableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a uitableview

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let width = tableView.frame.width - CGFloat((start*2))
        
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.frame.origin.x = 0
        headerView.frame.origin.y = -45
        headerView.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.width
     let desc = UILabel()
        desc.frame.origin.x = label.frame.origin.x
        desc.frame.origin.y = line.frame.maxY + 10
        desc.frame.size.width = width
        
        desc.numberOfLines = 0
        desc.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 17);
        desc.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.53, green: 0.53, blue: 0.53, alpha: 1.00)
        desc.text = self.data.desc
        desc.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        desc.textAlignment = .left
        desc.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
     
        if (loadMoreDesc) {
            desc.sizeToFit()
        } else {
            desc.frame.size.height = 110
        }
        headerView.addSubview(desc)
        
        
        let moreButtonDesc = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: desc.frame.minX, y: desc.frame.maxY, width: 80, height: 15))
        moreButtonDesc.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
        moreButtonDesc.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
        
        if (loadMoreDesc) {
             moreButtonDesc.setTitle("Less", for: .normal)
        } else {
             moreButtonDesc.setTitle("More", for: .normal)
        }
        moreButtonDesc.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 15);
        moreButtonDesc.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.48, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00), for: .normal)
        moreButtonDesc.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.expandDesc(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(moreButtonDesc)
```

When people click on "More" button the description should expand and the height of the table view header should increase to fit the description (desc). How can I accomplish this? Here's my expandDesc function

```
@objc func expandDesc(sender: UIButton) {
    loadMoreDesc = !loadMoreDesc
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Please note that the description is of dynamic height. I won’t know the height to set for the header unless I know the height of the description.

Answer (score 0):

please can you try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     if loadMoreDesc {
        return 100
      } else {
        return 50.0
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the issue is that the description is dynamic of height. I don't know it's height.